# The 'thank you' tooltip after flagging a comment is badly positioned

Tags: bug, design, comments, tooltips

When flagging a comment we see a "thank you" tooltip that gets activated via JavaScript for 5 seconds or so.

The problem is this tooltip shows up in the top-right corner of the screen rather than down where the comment was located. I thought it might be because I have user styles enabled, but I disabled them and the issue still occurs (I'm in Firefox 61 on Windows 7, though the issue occurs for me on Windows 10 as well).

The issue is the CSS styles in primary-unified.css for this, specifically `position: fixed`:

```css
.message.toast {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

AFAIK there are no transformed ancestors of this element, so that means the `position:fixed` property is applied to the viewport's initial containing block, and the modal is appearing 30px right and 20px down from the top-right corner of the viewport.

This can be fixed by changing the `position` value to something like `relative` and/or a few other things.

Example of the problem:

[image: Circled thank-you modal in the top-right corner of my screen]

This has been an issue since shortly after the new comment changes went live.

Comment: Luckily, it's already [meta-tag:status-planned]

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks, I couldn't find a dupe when searching/typing the title and was a little surprised.

Comment: and they change it for all the comments now ... before it was there only for the comments that get deleted automatically [like described in the dupe] but actually it's for every flag

Comment: *Why did you become a moderator?* - *Because the thank you pop up at the corner was annoying*

Comment: @TemaniAfif From what I recall, it has popped up for every comment flag since the big commenting change several days ago. Unless that's what you mean.

Comment: @TylerH yes but there was an intermediate step between, previously it was all the time within the comment section and now all the time on the top right BUT there was a period where we had both, for automatic deleted comments it was on the top right and for other it was under the comment.